# How to save jsoup parsed html after quiting the app?

Tags: java, android

in my application I use jsoup to get html to string (and that string I use in textview), but when I close the app, the textview is (obviously) blank. Do you know to save the data to be seen after starting the app?

Comment: Write it to a file.

Comment: Cache it. Put that text in a local db, like Realm.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about Realm. I have only tried sqlite but for some reason it didn't work. Writing it to file didn't work either.